# SQLite environment for Symfony 4.1

Tags: symfony, sqlite, symfony4

On a brand new project (Symfony 4.1), I tried to work with a **SQLite** database.
So I change the **.env** as it said :

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

File **doctrine.yaml** look like

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

But when I try to create the database :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

This error occurs :

```
In CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php line 78:
Connection does not contain a 'path' or 'dbname' parameter and cannot be dropped.
```

The fact is that `url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'` can't recursivly resolve the `%kernel.project_dir%` part of my **.env** config.
It seems to be a known issue that has been fixed for Symfony 3.4 in 2017 (So I can bet that has been fixed for more recent branches like 4.1 since 2017)

Interresting Source :

https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/129

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/23901

Please note that I found 2 workarounds in file **doctrine.yaml** :

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db'
```

But cleary (as mentioned) I should not modify that parameter...
Or

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        url: 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db'
```

Of course, it is more clean to fill in the sqlite connexion string in **.env** file than **doctrine.yaml** file because it depends on environment settings...

Do you have any idea how to make it works in **.env** file ?

Comment: any progress on this?